# Express route middleware cause 404

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express app that has route, that is called in app.js, as following

```
module.exports = function(app, db){
    app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views/users.html'));
    });
};
```

I also have the this middleware that is used before the error handling middleware at my app.js file

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

The problem is that when the middleware is not commented the user route return 404, but when the middleware is commented the route users work normally. Any idea what is happening

Answer (score 0):

You define error-handling middleware last, after other app.use() and routes calls;

So i think you define 404 before users routes. That's may be the issue.

Docs https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Actually the question wasn't clear so I edited it, this is not error handler that is a middleware that is used before the error-handling middleware which was already defined by express when the project was created.